# Is there a way to write all digits on documents in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, numbering, page-numbering

Is there a way to write all digits on documents consist of page number, fotnote number, enumerate number, etc. in math mode `$[number]$`?

because of in fonts of my language, the shape of math mode and text mode of digits are different and digits in text mode are ugly. I use `XeLaTeX` mode and the following changes are required:

1. page number
2. (sub,subsub)section and chapter numbers
3. enumerate numbers
4. footnote numbers
5. page numbers on index page
6. equation numbering

**Added (3-July-2018):**

when I using `setmainfont` with `Mapping=parsidigits` then all digits contain "zero" appear properly (as I wanted) but in this case we cannot use of other fonts for text. i.e. I cannot use both of `settextfont` `setmainfont` simultaneously.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\setmainfont[Mapping=parsidigits]{Yas}
%\settextfont{B Nazanin}
%\setdigitfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
    سلام. این یک متن ساده است.\footnote[10]{text}
    در زیر اعداد غیر ریاضی را مشاهده میکنید.
    0123456789
    و ریاضی
    $ 0123456789 $
    \section{بخش اول}
\lr{see numbers contain  "zero" in math mode and text mode without "Mapping=parsidigits"}
    \ptext[1-60]
\end{document}
```

There is another relative example in `fontspec` package, Example 22 on page 23.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but what would be the reason for doing such extensive work?

Comment: because of in fonts of my language, the  shape of math mode and text mode of digits are different and digits in text mode are ugly.

Comment: The solution method is likely going to depend on which text font and which math font you employ. Do please tell us about which fonts and/or font packages you employ. Do also reveal whether you employ pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, ConTeXt, or maybe some other TeX format.

Comment: I use XeLaTeX. Is it necessary to tell font name?

Comment: you could probably use a `\XeTeXintercharclass` for digits but in many setups the same is font used for math and text digits in which case there is nothing to do, what is the actual use case here.

Comment: There is a command for digits font: `\usedigitfont{font name}` but this does not change the page numbers, section numbers, etc.